# Problems with if() condition in Stan/RStan when modelling values from binomial random variable

Tags: r, statistics, stan, rstan

I'm trying to use Stan and R to fit a model that, uhh, models the observed realisations y_i = 16, 9, 10, 13, 19, 20, 18, 17, 35, 55, which are from a binomial distributed random variable, say, Y_i, with parameters m_i (number of trials) and p_i (success probability in each trial).

```
yi = c(16, 9, 10, 13, 19, 20, 18, 17, 35, 55)
```

For the purposes of this experiment, I'm going to assume that all of the m_i are fixed and given by m_i = 74, 99, 58, 70, 122, 77, 104, 129, 308, 119.

```
mi = c(74, 99, 58, 70, 122, 77, 104, 129, 308, 119)
```

I'm going to use Jeffrey's prior: \alpha=0.5 and \beta=0.5.

```
alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5
```

I'm trying to

1. Find Bayesian estimates for the p_i.
2. Find the range of the p_i (i.e., the parameters k as follows: [image]

My attempt at 2. is this section of code:

```
        real k;
        real mx = 0;
        real mn = 0;
        if (p > mx) 
          mx = p;
        if (mn > p) {
          mn = p;
        }
        k = mx - mn;
```

My Stan code is as follows:

````
```{stan output.var="BinModBeta"}
  data {
    int <lower = 1> mi[10];
    int <lower = 0> yi[10];
    real <lower = 0> alpha;
    real <lower = 0> beta;
  }

  parameters {
    real <lower = 0, upper = 1> p[10];
  }

  transformed parameters {
    real k;
    real mx = 0;
    real mn = 0;
    if (p > mx) 
      mx = p;
    if (mn > p) {
      mn = p;
    }
    k = mx - mn;
  }

  model {
    yi ~ binomial(mi, p);
    p ~ beta(alpha, beta);
  }
```
````

My R code is as follows:

````
```{r}
library(rstan)
```

```{r}
data.in <- list(mi = c(74, 99, 58, 70, 122, 77, 104, 129, 308, 119), yi = c(16, 9, 10, 13, 19, 20, 18, 17, 35, 55), alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5)
model.fit1 <- sampling(BinModBeta, data=data.in)
```

```{r}
print(model.fit1, pars = c("p"), probs=c(0.1,0.5,0.9), digits = 5)
```
````

Now, I just started learning Stan, so I'm honestly not sure if this is correct at all. However, it *seems* like this code works for my first aim (at least, whatever I've coded seems to work ...). **But my trouble starts when attempting to code my second aim.**

When I attempt to compile the Stan code above, I get the following error:

[image]

Now, based on this error message, it seems like my issue is arising from the fact that p is a vector of 10 real values, rather than a single real. However, due to my inexperience with Stan, I'm unsure of how to get around this problem.

Comment: Well you declared `p` as a real vector of length 10 in your `parameters` block. So this causes the error in the `if` statement.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for the response. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try declaring `p` as a real scalar.

Comment: @MauritsEvers But I need it to be a vector of size 10 since we have i = 10, right?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand what you’re trying to model. What is `m_1`? What are you doing in the `transformed parameters` block? I see little connection between the problem statement and your model. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @MauritsEvers `mi` are just the values 74, 99, 58, 70, 122, 77, 104, 129, 308, 119. In the `transformed parameters` block, I am simply attempting to do what I said for problem 2 (find the range of the p_i). If we take out the code that I described as "my attempt at 2.", then we are left with the code that addresses problem 1. But, as far as I can see, my code is working for problem 1 but is not working for problem 2, which is what I'm asking for help with. As you said, since `p` is a vector of real numbers, it isn't working for my if statements. So how do I fix this?

Comment: *What* values are `mi`. The number of trials? Be precise! “Just the values” doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, `mi` is the number of trials. I apologise for not being clear. I will edit the main post.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below, and the comments at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
model <- "
data {
  int <lower = 1> mi[10];
  int <lower = 0> yi[10];
  real <lower = 0> alpha;
  real <lower = 0> beta;
}

parameters {
  real <lower = 0, upper = 1> p[10];
}

model {
    p ~ beta(alpha, beta);        // Prior
    yi ~ binomial(mi, p);         // Likelihood
}

generated quantities {
    real k;
    k = max(p) - min(p);
}
"

library(rstan);
yi = c(16, 9, 10, 13, 19, 20, 18, 17, 35, 55);
mi = c(74, 99, 58, 70, 122, 77, 104, 129, 308, 119);
fit <- stan(
    model_code = model,
    data = list(mi = mi, yi = yi, alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5))
fit;
#Inference for Stan model: 6a01a3b25656e1b18183baf19183abf7.
#4 chains, each with iter=2000; warmup=1000; thin=1;
#post-warmup draws per chain=1000, total post-warmup draws=4000.
#
#         mean se_mean   sd    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5% n_eff Rhat
#p[1]     0.22    0.00 0.05    0.13    0.19    0.22    0.25    0.32  4000    1
#p[2]     0.10    0.00 0.03    0.05    0.07    0.09    0.11    0.16  4000    1
#p[3]     0.18    0.00 0.05    0.09    0.14    0.17    0.21    0.28  4000    1
#p[4]     0.19    0.00 0.05    0.11    0.16    0.19    0.22    0.29  4000    1
#p[5]     0.16    0.00 0.03    0.10    0.14    0.16    0.18    0.22  4000    1
#p[6]     0.26    0.00 0.05    0.17    0.23    0.26    0.30    0.37  4000    1
#p[7]     0.18    0.00 0.04    0.11    0.15    0.17    0.20    0.25  4000    1
#p[8]     0.13    0.00 0.03    0.08    0.11    0.13    0.15    0.20  4000    1
#p[9]     0.11    0.00 0.02    0.08    0.10    0.11    0.13    0.15  4000    1
#p[10]    0.46    0.00 0.04    0.38    0.43    0.46    0.49    0.55  4000    1
#k        0.38    0.00 0.05    0.28    0.34    0.38    0.41    0.47  4000    1
#lp__  -530.01    0.05 2.26 -535.38 -531.33 -529.65 -528.37 -526.69  1782    1
#
#Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Tue Apr 24 22:02:07 2018.
#For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
#and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split chains (at
#convergence, Rhat=1).
```

Comments:

1. I would move the part involving the calculation of `k` into the `generated quantities` block; this has to do with the different program blocks being executed at different times. While the `transformed parameters` block is executed once every leapfrog step, the `generated quantities` block is only executed once per sample draw. So there will be less overhead in recalculating `k`. See e.g. [here](http://mlss2014.hiit.fi/mlss_files/2-stan.pdf) for details. Note that uncertainties from the `pi` posterior densities get properly propagated to `k`.
2. You can make use of `Stan`s internal `max`,`min` functions when calculating `k`. This will be faster than determining the min/max of `pi` with `if` conditions, and also eliminates the need to define `mn` and `mx`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer; your help is greatly appreciated. Indeed, using the `max` and `min` functions was also part of my new solution, so it's good to see that I got something right. However, your idea of moving `k` to the `generated quantities` block is totally novel to me! Very interesting indeed. Also, it seems that we got the same output, which begs the question of my other thread: If our maximum value for `p` is 0.46, and the minimum value for `p` is 0.10, then we have that `k` = 0.46 - 0.10 = 0.36, right? But we have that k = 0.38, which seems to contradict this?

Comment: Other thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/342470/modelling-parameter-r-max-limits-i-1-dots-10-p-i-min-limits-i

Comment: @ThePointer I'd actually say that `k=0.36` is in *excellent agreement* with `k=0.38`, given the credible intervals given for `k`. Just to clarify on the first part of your comment: There was nothing wrong with leaving the `k` calculation in the `transformed parameters` part; it's just less efficient and not really necessary; the `transformed parameters` block is important when you need to calculate quantities prior to updating the posterior (which is not the case here for `k`).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for sharing your wisdom. This has been very enlightening for me.

Comment: @ThePointer Concerning your question from CV: Keep in mind that uncertainties propagate. Consider `mx` and `mn` with their associated standard deviations. We're working in a Bayesian framework, but let's consider for a moment the classic propagation of uncertainties: For a derived quantity `k = mx - mn`, the uncertainties propagate according to: `(sd(k)/k)^2 = (sd(mx)/mx)^2 + (sd(mn)/mn)^2`. In other words, the squared relative uncertainty in `k` will be equal to the sum of the squared relative uncertainties in `mx` and `mn`. [...]

Comment: [continued] In a fully Bayesian framework you're not looking at point estimates but at the full posterior densities. It's not a suprise that point estimates don't "add up", because you're ignoring uncertanties and their non-linear propagation (which also occurs within a non-Bayesian framework, as just demonstrated).

Comment: @ThePointer Glad it was helpful. It was a good and interesting question. Thanks for the discussion.